# Using left joins instead of sub queries in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have been told I could use left joins instead of sub queries like the one below  can anyone help me understand how...thanks.

I need to get the serial numbers of devices that have not been seen in the last 5 years.  This data is across two different databases and the serials are in a third database.  If you have other pointers to assist in running this query smoother I welcome them.

this is to look for Workorders for accounts that were in the HeadEnd file and not in the snapshot and have not been seen in over 5 years (to be run on db-prod).

```
use vcr6_prod
go 

select * from [GC-DEV-TEST\TEST2008R2].TeriResearch.dbo.comedheadend20131216
where Serial in (
select 
--sa.ObservedComplete,
--pwo.wo_completedate,
----wod.d_ID,
----wod.wo_id,
--pwo.wo_id,
--woi.UserList0,
--wo.userdata0
--distinct 
cehe.serial 
--*
from
[GC-DEV-TEST\TEST2008R2].TeriResearch.dbo.comedheadend20131216 cehe
join [GC-DEV-TEST\TEST2008R2].TeriResearch.dbo.ComEd120131115 ce
                               on cehe.premise_desc = ce.PremiseNbr

join OutReach25.dbo.Premise p on p.PremiseDesc = cehe.premise_desc

join OutReach25.dbo.CustomerPremise cp on cp.PremiseID = p.PremiseID 
left join [vcr6_prod].dbo.workorder wo 
                                       on convert (varchar, cp.premiseid) = wo.account 
join VCR6_PROD.dbo.WorkOrderItem woi on woi.WorkOrder = wo.workorder 
                                            and woi.Serial = cehe.serial 
left join [colo-db1].ComedNF_IL.dbo.p_workorder pwo
                                           on wo.userdata0 = pwo.wo_number 
left join ScheduleAssignment sa 
                                           on wo.WorkOrder = sa.WorkOrderId 

where wo.BranchId = 'comed'
and cp.ProjectID = 55

and       (    
             pwo.wo_completedate < DateAdd(yy, -5, GetDate())
             or 
             (
                   sa.ObservedComplete < DateAdd(yy, -5, GetDate()) 
                   and
                   sa.ObservedComplete <> '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000'
              )
          ))
      and Serial not in
      (
select 
--sa.ObservedComplete,
--pwo.wo_completedate,
----wod.d_ID,
----wod.wo_id,
--pwo.wo_id,
--woi.UserList0,
--wo.userdata0
--distinct 
cehe.serial 
--*
from
[GC-DEV-TEST\TEST2008R2].TeriResearch.dbo.comedheadend20131216 cehe
join [GC-DEV-TEST\TEST2008R2].TeriResearch.dbo.ComEd120131115 ce
                               on cehe.premise_desc = ce.PremiseNbr

join OutReach25.dbo.Premise p on p.PremiseDesc = cehe.premise_desc

join OutReach25.dbo.CustomerPremise cp on cp.PremiseID = p.PremiseID 
left join [vcr6_prod].dbo.workorder wo 
                                       on convert (varchar, cp.premiseid) = wo.account 
join VCR6_PROD.dbo.WorkOrderItem woi on woi.WorkOrder = wo.workorder 
                                            and woi.Serial = cehe.serial 
left join [colo-db1].ComedNF_IL.dbo.p_workorder pwo
                                           on wo.userdata0 = pwo.wo_number 
left join ScheduleAssignment sa 
                                           on wo.WorkOrder = sa.WorkOrderId 

where wo.BranchId = 'comed'
and cp.ProjectID = 55

and       (    
             pwo.wo_completedate > DateAdd(yy, -5, GetDate())
             or 
             (
                   sa.ObservedComplete > DateAdd(yy, -5, GetDate()) 
                   and
                   sa.ObservedComplete <> '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000'
              )
          ))




--and sa.ObservedComplete is not null
```

Comment: `An advice` : questions with such a longgggggggggggggggg code doesnt get much attention as not many people fancy going throw tens of lines of code. Stimulate your problem with a smaller piece of code and be direct about what is it that you are struggling with.

Comment: thank you for the advice.  broken down, what I am trying to do is:
select * from table_A 
where X in
( Select X From Table_C
where column_1 is > 5)
and where X not in 
( Select X From Table_C
where column_1 is < 5)

Table C is a Workorder table and will have multiple rows with duplicate values Column_X.  I am trying to find devices that Have not been services in the past 5 years.  Does this make the water any clearer?
Thanks again for your input.  It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To emulate a NOT IN using a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT table1.columns
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.key
WHERE table2.key is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your Query**

```
select * from table_A 
where X in ( Select X From Table_C 
             where column_1 is > 5) 
and where X not in ( Select X From Table_C 
                    where column_1 is < 5)
```

Now if you look closer your both condition is where clause if checking against the same condition.

**Test Data**

Now to achieve same output with help of joins see below

```
DECLARE @Table_A TABLE (X INT, Column_1 INT)
INSERT INTO @Table_A 
VALUES 
(1, 100),(2, 200),(3, 300),
(4, 400),(5, 500),(6, 600),
(7, 700),(8, 800),(9, 900)

DECLARE @Table_C TABLE (X INT, Column_1 INT)
INSERT INTO @Table_C 
VALUES 
(1, 100),(2, 200),(3, 300),
(4, 400),(5, 500),(6, 600),
(7, 700),(8, 800),(9, 900)
```

**Query**

My suggestion with joins and only checking against One condition that you have mentioned your where clause.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM @Table_A A INNER JOIN @Table_C C
ON A.X = C.X
WHERE C.Column_1 > 500
```

Using joins checking against both conditions mentioned in your query.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM @Table_A A INNER JOIN @Table_C C
ON A.X = C.X
INNER JOIN @Table_C D
ON A.X = D.X
WHERE C.Column_1 > 500
AND D.Column_1 !< 500
```

But both queries will return exactly the same results. as follows

**Results Set**

```
╔═══╦══════════╗
║ X ║ Column_1 ║
╠═══╬══════════╣
║ 6 ║      600 ║
║ 7 ║      700 ║
║ 8 ║      800 ║
║ 9 ║      900 ║
╚═══╩══════════╝
```

I dont think you need to check against both conditions in your where clause. Since Both condition are logically the same.

Its like me saying `I am not a Teenager` AND `I am not Less then 20 years old` :)